# MySQL Counting Distinct Values on Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, distinct

I wrote a script that runs each time a user logs into a computer in our domain.  This script makes a record of the user as well as the computer they logged into.  Any number of users can log into any number of computers.

I just inherited this IT environment from a consultant who is no longer around, and I'm writing this little query so when I get a call from a user, I can search by that user's name and reasonably predict which computer they are using by the number of times they've logged into any given computer.

Here's a sample of the data in the 'login' table:

```
    COMPUTER        USER
    ncofp02         lee
    ncofp02         lee
    ncofp02         andy
    ncodc01         andy
    ncodc01         andy
    ncodc01         lee
```

What I'm banging my head on is the logic to count distinct values across multiple columns.  I'd like to see a result like this:

```
    COMPUTER       USER   COUNT
    ncofp02        lee    (2)
    ncofp02        andy   (1)
    ncodc01        lee    (1)
    ncodc01        andy   (2)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with a single query within mysql, or should I start looping some php? (booooo!)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just list multiple columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT computer, user, count(*) AS count
FROM login
GROUP BY computer, user
```

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe it was seriously THAT easy.  LOL I guess I must have been overthinking.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
SELECT l.computer, l.user, COUNT(DISTINCT l.computer, l.user) AS count
FROM login l 
GROUP BY l.computer, l.user
```

Comment: You don't need DISTINCT if you're counting the same thing you're grouping by.

Answer (score 3):

Easy!

```
SELECT 
    computer, user, COUNT(DISTINCT computer, user) AS count
FROM 
    login
```