# Count distinct values over multiple columns

Tags: mysql

Similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809639/mysql-counting-distinct-values-on-multiple-columns) however I want to count how many different distinct 
values appear for one user_id. If I had the following table:

```
USER_ID  DATA
123      abc
234      abc
123      def
456      def
123      abc
```

I would want the following results:

```
USER_ID  COUNT
123      2
234      1
456      1
```

Because '123' has both 'abc' and 'def' data values, where as '234' and '456' only have the one distinct data value.

Currently I have the following pseudo-code:

```
rows = SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table
for for in rows:
     result = SELECT DISTINCT user_id, data FROM table WHERE user_id = <row>
     if result.rowcount > 2:
          doSomething()
```

But this takes a long time as it has to make a call for each user_id.

Can this be done in one MySQL command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `COUNT()` aggregation along with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT data) AS distinct_data_count
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty, but can't you do

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT data) as dc from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c2e1/5/0)

```
select user_id, count(distinct dat) from test
group by user_id
```