# Count unique fields mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this in mysql:

```
dancer1 | dancer2
------------------
jeff    | Julia
john    | Megan
jeff    | Vanessa
```

I should be easy, but how do I count the number of unique dancers (in this case 5) The problem looks like questionned here: [MySQL Counting Distinct Values on Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809639/mysql-counting-distinct-values-on-multiple-columns), but not quite

Comment: you need the count as 5 as given here..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple union will give you a set of all dancers:

```
select DISTINCT dancer1 as dancer from table
union 
select DISTINCT dancer2 as dancer from table
```

And if you want the count:

```
select count(all_dancers.dancer) from (    
     select DISTINCT dancer1 as dancer from table
     union 
     select DISTINCT dancer2 as dancer from table
) all_dancers
```

Comment: @safinchacko I don't think a distinct is possible on multiple columns at the same time. I just tried it out in MySQL

Comment: Only with UNION the count is right, thanks @shravster !

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select  count( distinct dancer1,dancer2  ) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dancer) 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT dancer1 dancer 
         FROM my_table 
        UNION 
       SELECT dancer2 
         FROM my_table
     ) x;
```